# HierarchicalDataTemplate Skip Hierarchy

Tags: .net, wpf, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a data structure like

Level1
    --Level2
        ----Level3
           ------Level4

shown in a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. This is so far ok, but i would like to skip Level 2 & 3, so that Level 4 is directly under Level 1. Is that even possible?

Comment: You can try to set visibility to Collapsed of the controls for Level 2 and Level 3

Comment: Not really, setting level 2 to collapsed will also collapse all of its children. Same for hidden. Setting Level 3 to visible again doesn't help too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create new structure model and use `Converter` to convert from one structure to another.

Comment: Is there any possibility to do that without altering the data(or viewmodel)? So do it only in xaml??

Comment: @opiswahn: Another way is to define a custom `ControlTemplate` for `TreeView`. But, by my opinion, it is much easier to use `Converter`.